# Crop Plane to Polygon using Coordinates (Python)

Tags: python, modifiers, knife-tool

I want to crop a textured plane to a polygon defined by a set of world coordinates.

The process must be scriptable using Python.

Something like the knife tool, except using defined points instead of interactive points, would be perfect.

I have tried generating a SVG defining the polygon, and using a Boolean Intersection modifier, but this does not work with non-manifold geometries like planes.

It seems that there should be an easier way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Am of the opinion that boolean will work with a plane.  Give the cutting object some thickness with a solidify modifier.

Comment: This all sounds like the long way around. Creating a shape in SVG, importing it, converting it to mesh, cutting another geometry, when you already have the correct shape, sounds like a lot of trouble for no good reason. Why not not simply apply the same material to the svg curve instead?